# Copy assignment for class member functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `A` with some member functions that all do the same thing.

```py
class A:
  def a():
    ... boilerplate code ...
  
  b = c = d = a
```

For debugging reasons, I would like to know the name of each member function at runtime. But since they all point to the same memory address, they will have the same `__name__` attribute and I cannot figure out a way to distinguish between `A.a` and `A.b` just by looking at the object.

```py
a = A.a
b = A.b
a.__name__ == b.__name__ # this is true
# how do I tell the difference between a and b?
```

Is there a way to achieve this without manually creating the functions `b`, `c` and `d` with the same boilerplate code?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why do you have these aliases in the first place, and why do you care about distinguishing which name was used by the caller in order to call the method? Keep in mind that the caller could equally well have made a local alias for the method anyway. You cannot make a distinction just by looking at the object, *exactly because it is the same object* - so why does anything else matter?

Comment: Apologizes for the misleading post, I do not want them to be the same object. What I was trying to say; is there a way to define different methods with the same body without having to writing them down individually? I want these methods to be different objects.

Comment: ... But I'm still confused. What do you accomplish by having separate objects for separate methods that do exactly the same thing?

Comment: I understand the confusion, but the reason for having this isn't really the point of my question. But in my particular case I want to treat the methods separately and overload them at runtime. So yes, initially these methods will do exactly the same thing, but they will change behaviour depending on what state the program is in.

Comment: You could dynamically create the methods, but now I think you're getting into a slightly different question and we'd want to see more specifics on how the system needs to work.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to dynamically create the methods instead of manually doing it. I tried with a for-loop but had no luck there.

Comment: Hmm, I understand how this is unclear now. I want to generate code that creates different methods that do the same thing. So effectively I am manually adding each method to the class, but just looking at the code I want to do this conveniently, with 1 line code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Objects and names in Python live in separate spaces.  There's only one function object there, and the function object doesn't know through what name it was conjured.

If you were a masochist, I suppose it would be possible to get a traceback and look at the line of code that called you, but that's just not practical.

You could do something like:

```
    def reala(self,me=None):
        pass
    def a(self):
        return reala('a')
    def b(self):
        return reala('b')
    ...
```